# Difference between ParseRole and ParseRelation

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

Can somebody please explain to me the exact differences between a `ParseRole` and a `ParseRelation`? I'm trying to figure out which one is more suitable for me to use and so far I can't see many differences. I originally thought that `ParseRole` was a many-to-many relationship and `ParseRelation` was a one-to-many, however it appears they're both many-to-many. Any light shed on the matter would be of great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ParseRole is a term used to define the role a User has, that is, what objects it can access. It is used in conjunction with ACLs (Access Control Lists) to add a layer of data security, ensuring only valid users access it.

Imagine a game whose backend is provided by Parse, this game has user generated levels and there's a group of players denoted "moderators". Moderators can delete other's levels if it breaks the game's rules. You only want them to be able to delete any level, so you create a role named `moderator` and assign delete permissions to it in the `Level` class' ACL.

ParseRelation, in the other hand, is a many-to-many relation between any kind of object.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense for `ParseRole` but I still don't really know when I'd use a `ParseRelation` over a `ParseRole`.

Comment: Roles only serve the purpose of limiting access to objects, relations can express anything between two sets of objects.

Comment: So an example of using a `ParseRelation` would be?

Comment: A Facebook user and their posts.

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate. Really helpful. I've decided to use Roles for my solution then.

Comment: It would be useful to add more explanation of the `ParseRelation` to your answer, also bonus points for talking about arrays of pointers for lightweight use.